# Mysql - how to get the max value of a varchar column

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows ID is a numeric column and Total is Varchar(20) - table name is orders:

```
ID       Total

1        $10

2        $1,000

3        $1500.50

4        300

5        20.50

6        -80
```

through a

```
SELECT statement I would like to get the Id of the highest total i.e 3. 

SELECT ID, MAX(CONVERT(Total, SIGNED INTEGER)) AS total FROM orders
```

gives me the highest total but incorrect ID.

I would like to ignore the dollar sign `($)` and comma `(,)`.

Answer (score 3):

just use 
`MAX(CONVERT(replace(replace(total,',',''),'$',''), SIGNED INTEGER)) AS total`

Comment: This answer would be better if the conversion were to a numeric value, such as float or real, since the numbers in question have decimal points.

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be like this. It works, I have used it too.

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(CONVERT({column_name}, SIGNED INTEGER)) AS {column_name or xyz_name} from {table_name}
```

Answer (score 1):

Storing money amounts in VARCHAR field sounds like asking for trouble.

You can try to remove leading `$` using `REPLACE` before converting to number, but it is still wrong thing to do.

Please rework your schema and store money amounts in appropriately typed columns, and these problems will not arise.